# Is Lisa quoting something else in Deep Space Homer, or did the writers write this themselves?

Tags: dialogue, reference, the-simpsons

In the *Simpsons* episode [Deep Space Homer](http://www.snpp.com/episodes/1F13.html), when the space shuttle is taking off, Lisa says this:

> How doth the hero strong and brave, a celestial path in the heavens pave.

Is this a reference to something else (poem/play etc) or did the writers come up with this themselves?

Comment: Good question. The only non-Simpsons reference to it I found was in a blog post mentioning [For All Mankind (1989)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097372/), however I found the subtitles for it and it doesn't appear in there, so I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Between the title and "celestial path", it sounds like a reference to [Deep Space Nine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine) and the wormhole - the Bajoran prophecies referred to it in a few ways, most often the Celestial Temple.  It doesn't bring to mind any specific quote, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The saying is not a famous quote.

Precocious young Lisa is trying to sound smart by using sophisticated words like "doth" and "celestial" in a rhyme. Ever the intelligent overachiever, she's essentially trying to come up with a wisely worded quote of her own. But "hero strong and brave" is actually quite a cheesy, uninspired bit of phrase-making. And the use of "pave" to describe laying a pathway is a clear reach for something to rhyme with brave.

Before you take a second to think about it, the quote sounds impressive and potentially historical -- but it definitely isn't. That's the joke.

Comment: Not to mention that "celestial" is redundant with "in the heavens".